# How to get the list of employees and their reporting level recursively using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, recursive-query

I have a table for list of employees with their supervisors.

```
| UserID | SupervisorUserId |
|--------|------------------|
| 10     | null             |
| 1      | 10               |
| 2      | 1                |
| 3      | 1                |
| 4      | 3                |
| 5      | 10               |
| 6      | 5                |
| 7      | 6                |
| 8      | 6                |
| 9      | 8                |
```

Here's a diagram for visualisation:

[image: Employee hierarchy chart]

And here's what I have right now:

```cs
public JsonResult GetEmployeesWithReportingLevel()
{
    try
    {

        var getEmployees = GetEmployees().ToList();

        var employeeList = (from e in getEmployees
                            where e.IsDeleted != true
                            select new ReportingLineList
                            {
                                UserId = e.UserId,
                                SupervisorId = e.SupervisorId 
                            }).ToList();

        var reportingLevel = (from emp in employeeList
                                select new 
                                {
                                    UserId = emp.UserId,
                                    ReportingLevel = GetReportingLevel(employeeList, emp.UserId, 0)
                                }).ToList();

        return new JsonResult(reportingLevel);
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

```cs
private int GetReportingLevel(IEnumerable<ReportingLineList> employeeList, Guid UserId, int reportingLevel)
{
    try
    {
        var reportingEmployees = (from emp in employeeList
                                        where emp.SupervisorId == UserId
                                        select new 
                                        {
                                            UserId = emp.UserId
                                        }).ToList();

        foreach (var emp in reportingEmployees)
        {
            if (emp.UserId != null)
            {
                return GetReportingLevel(employeeList, (Guid)emp.UserId, reportingLevel + 1);
            }
        }

        return reportingLevel;
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

My expected result should be:

```
| UserId | Reporting level |
|--------|-----------------|
| 2      | 0               |
| 4      | 0               |
| 7      | 0               |
| 9      | 0               |
| 3      | 1               |
| 8      | 1               |
| 1      | 2               |
| 6      | 3               |
| 5      | 3               |
| 10     | 4               |
```

With my current result, it seems like it is just iterating with the first employee that my code will get.

Here's the result that I'm getting.

```
| UserId | Reporting level |
|--------|-----------------|
| 2      | 0               |
| 4      | 0               |
| 7      | 0               |
| 9      | 0               |
| 3      | 1               |
| 8      | 1               |
| 1      | 1               |
| 6      | 1               |
| 5      | 2               |
| 10     | 3               |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you say you expect UserId 6 to have a reporting level of 3, but if I understand the problem, then both data and diagram would suggest it should be 2.

If that is correct, then the problem is with your GetReportingLevel method. You need to keep a track of both the currentLevel and the MaximumReportingLevel. Every time you descend a level you need to increase currentLevel and then decrease it again when you have finished with that level and this needs to be independent of MaximumReportingLevel, which should only change if it finds a deeper level than before.

For example, when you are processing Employee 10 you recursively process Employee 1 on level 1 and then Employee 2 on Level 2, but then you need to go back to Level 1 to process Employee 3 while not losing the fact that your maximum level was 2.

Your code also does not compile for me, e.g. is UserID an int or a Guid etc, but I think the following should work
(I have deliberately tried to leave most of your code as is)

```
private int GetReportingLevel(IEnumerable<ReportingLineList> employeeList, Guid UserId, 
                              int MaxReportingLevel = 0, int CurrentLevel = 0)
{
    try
    {
        var reportingEmployees = (from emp in employeeList
                                  where emp.SupervisorId == UserId
                                  select new
                                  {
                                      UserId = emp.UserId
                                  }).ToList();

        CurrentLevel++;
        foreach (var emp in reportingEmployees)
        {
            if (emp.UserId != null)
            {
                int newLevel = GetReportingLevel(employeeList, (Guid)emp.UserId,
                                                 MaxReportingLevel , CurrentLevel);
            
                MaxReportingLevel = Math.Max(currentLevel, newLevel);
            }
        }
        CurrentLevel--;

        return MaxReportingLevel;
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I am kinda new also, but it seems like your problem can just be fixed by adding an `.OrderBy()` if I'm not mistaken.

Here is a link to check it out: [MSDN Enumerable.OrderBy Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=net-6.0)

Comment: For answer's with link(s), it is advisable  to highlight the important details or provide a summary regarding what you found in the link you provided. Because time will come that the link will be unavailable/invalid.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could simplify your recursion method. Passing a reporting level as an input parameter should not be necessary.

Considering the expected output you have provided for the example input and associated diagram, I'd say the implementation logic can be put into words as follows:

1. If *no one* is reporting to employee `X`, then employee `X` has reporting level `0`
2. Otherwise, employee `X`'s reporting level is *one higher than the highest reporting level of all employees that are reporting directly to employee `X`*

From how I interpret your current implementation of `GetReportingLevel()`, I believe you are addressing the first statement and most of the second statement, but missing the **the highest** part of *one higher than **the highest** reporting level of all employees that are reporting directly to employee `X`* in the second statement.

In pseudocode, I would reflect the logic in the two statements as as follows in the recursion method:

```csharp
int GetReportingLevel(<all employees>, <employee / user ID>)
{
    // Find all the employees in <all employees> that report directly to <employee>

    // If no employees report directly to <employee>:
    // return 0

    // Otherwise:
    // return 1
    //    + the maximum reporting level of all employees that report directly to <employee>
}
```

I'll refer to *all the employees that report directly to <employee>* as the *subordinates of <employee>*.

A rather straight-forward implementation of this pseudocode is:

```csharp
private static int GetReportingLevel(IEnumerable<ReportingLineList> employeeList, int userId)
{
    var subordinates = employeeList
        .Where(emp => emp.SupervisorUserId == userId);
    
    if (!subordinates.Any())
    {
        return 0;
    }
    
    return 1 + subordinates.Max(sub => GetReportingLevel(employeeList, sub.UserId));
}
```

Example fiddle for the straight-forward approach [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tnpgUr).

---

In the straight-forward implementation, though, you will basically traverse the whole subtree of an employee and calculate the reporting levels of *all of the employee's descendants* to be able to calculate the *one* employee's reporting level, even if you have already traversed part of the subtree (or even the whole subtree!) beforehand during the calculation of *another* employee's reporting level.

To provide an example, I'll borrow your diagram:

[image: reporting regime of employees visualized in a diagram]

If you start by calculating the reporting level of `Emp 10`, you will traverse the *whole* tree just to calculate the reporting level of `Emp 10` (blue area), seeing as the reporting levels are computed from the leaf nodes and upwards. When you then move on to calculate the reporting level of `Emp 1`, you will redo *a subset of all the recursive calls that were just made* when calculating the reporting level of `Emp 10` (orange area).

We want to minimize the amount of recursive calls whenever we have the chance. I'd suggest using a dictionary to keep track of which reporting levels we have already calculated, and simply getting the reporting level from the dictionary whenever we need it and it has already been calculated.

The pseudocode for such an implementation could be:

```csharp
// dictionary with key <user ID> and value <reporting level>

int GetReportingLevel(<all employees>, <employee / user ID>)
{
    // If my dictionary already has an entry for <employee>:
    // return the reporting level from the dictionary

    // Otherwise: Find all the employees in <all employees>
    //    that report directly to <employee>

    // Calculate the reporting level for <employee>
    //    (using the same logic as in the straight-forward implementation)
    //    and add <employee's user ID> and their reporting level to the dictionary

    // return the reporting level that was just calculated for <employee>
}
```

The implementation may look like:

```csharp
private static Dictionary<int, int> _reportingLevelForUserId = new();

private static int GetReportingLevel(IEnumerable<ReportingLineList> employeeList, int userId)
{
    if (_reportingLevelForUserId.TryGetValue(userId, out var reportingLevel))
    {
        return reportingLevel;
    }
    
    var subordinates = employeeList
        .Where(emp => emp.SupervisorUserId == userId);
    
    _reportingLevelForUserId[userId] = subordinates.Any()
        ? 1 + subordinates.Max(sub => GetReportingLevel(employeeList, sub.UserId))
        : 0;
    
    return _reportingLevelForUserId[userId];
}
```

Example fiddle for the more optimized approach [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nV4ukH).

---

For the example input you have provided, the straight-forward approach results in 31 calls to `GetReportingLevel()`, whereas the dictionary-based approach results in 19 calls to `GetReportingLevel()`. For such a small tree, it may not make much of a difference; but the larger the tree, the more important such an optimization is.

In both of the implementations of `GetReportingLevel()`, I have assumed the following structure of the `ReportingLineList` class:

```csharp
public class ReportingLineList
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int? SupervisorUserId { get; set; }
}
```

If the output is calucated as follows:

```csharp
var employeesWithReportingLevel = employeeList
    .Select(employee => new
        {
            UserId = employee.UserId,
            ReportingLevel = GetReportingLevel(employeeList, employee.UserId)
        })
    .OrderBy(reportingEmployee => reportingEmployee.ReportingLevel)
    .ToList();
```

, either implementation of the method generates the following output for the given input:

```csharp
           Input                               Output
=============================        ===========================
                             
| UserID | SupervisorUserId |        | UserId | ReportingLevel |
|--------|------------------|        |--------|----------------|
|     10 |             null |        |      2 |              0 |
|      1 |               10 |        |      4 |              0 |
|      2 |                1 |        |      7 |              0 |
|      3 |                1 |        |      9 |              0 |
|      4 |                3 |        |      3 |              1 |
|      5 |               10 |        |      8 |              1 |
|      6 |                5 |        |      1 |              2 |
|      7 |                6 |        |      6 |              2 |
|      8 |                6 |        |      5 |              3 |
|      9 |                8 |        |     10 |              4 |
```